# How to use > for (variable in vector) { in R?

Tags: r, variables, vector

```
Site   Treatment    Month    repli
W2         0          0      2
W3         0          0      1 
W7         0          0      3
W12        0          0      4
W2         0          1      2
W3         0          1      1
W7         0          1      3 
W12        0          1      4
W2         0          3      2
W3         0          3      1
W7         0          3      3 
W12        0          3      4
W2         0          4      2
W3         0          4      1
W7         0          4      3 
W12        0          4      4
```

If I use

```
for(i in 1:max(data$Repli)){
s1=subset(data,data$Repli==i)
```

I get the last row (w12 one)

```
Site      Treatment   Month    repli
W12           0         0       4
W12           0         1       4
W12           0         3       4
W12           0         5       4
```

My question is how to select other rows?
What would be my code when I would like to select W2, W3 or W7?

Thank you!

I have to use the same script as i from the below script is being used elsewhere

```
for(i in 1:max(Cs$Repli)){
  s1=subset(Cs,Cs$Repli==i)
```

Comment: I think your current code should work OK for selecting each subset, but they will only be selected during the current loop iteration. As soon as you get to the next iteration and `s1` is overwritten, you don't have that subset any more. If you want to save all subsets you could use `subsets = split(data, data$repli)`

Comment: @Marius Thank you. However, (i) from above script    for(i in 1:max(data$Repli)){
s1=subset(data,data$Repli==i) is being used elsewhere too. So, I have to use to same code for other rows too. It is okay if it is over written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `%in%`:

```
data[data$Site %in% c("W2", "W3", "W7"), ]
```

Comment: Beigeleisen Thank you sir for quick reply.

Comment: I marked it. However there was a problem. The script that I was using    for(i in 1:max(Cs$Repli)){s1=subset(Cs,Cs$Repli==i). The i from above script is used else where too. So I cant use %in%. Since your script answered my specific question I have marked it.  Thanks!